# WPF форма в C# проекте WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть рабочее приложение, написанное на c#, с разными окошечками и рюшечками. Захотелось сделать его еще более цветастее, еще более не квадратным. Заморачиваться с ручной отрисовкой окна и регионами окна - это не столь красиво получается, да и приложение начинает существенно подтормаживать. Посоветовали поглядеть в сторону создания `WPF` окна. Однако, как вижу, его нельзя создать внутри проекта `WinForms` на `c#`. Я не доглядел что-то? Ведь элементы `WPF` через `ElementHost` можно же разместить, а форму получается создать нельзя?

Получится ли безболезненно перевести код программы на `WPF` проект? Отличие только в работе с визуальными контролами же, как я понял?

PS: Заранее спасибо за наводку.

Comment: Если у вас нет своих CustomControls или рисования на GDI+ или чего либо еще. Хотя на крайний случай можно в WPF разместить очень "крутые" WinForms компоненты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Получится ли безболезненно перевести код программы на WPF проект?

Все зависит от того, как реализовано текущее приложение. Если были соблюдены основный правила и приемы проектирования, а именно MVC или близкий к нему шаблон (например MVVM), то изменения коснутся в основном только UI.

В общем смысле всегда отделяйте логику функционирования программы от ее "внешнего вида". Если на форме есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую следует запрос к БД, при получении которого обновляется label1 и все это сделано в обработчике события, то у меня плохие новости. Такое приложение во-первых будет негибким (например, при переходе на новый UI придется менять все обрабочики), во-вторых нетестируемым из-за сильной зависимости компонентов. Неплохо разделять "уровни" программы по различным сборкам. Например, MyApp.UI - одна, MyApp.Logic - другай, MyApp.Data - третья. В таком случае при смене UI, скажем с WinForms на [ASP.Net](http://ASP.Net) MVC, нужно будет заменить только одну библиотеку с интерфейсом пользователя.

Подводя итог, если вы соблюдали описанные выше рекомендации, то переход на WPF займет минимальные трудозатраты, если же нет - то самое время изменить дизайн приложения.

> Отличие только в работе с визуальными контролами же, как я понял?

WPF использует DirextX для отрисовки компонентов, в отличии от устаревшего GDI дя WinForms. Кроме того, более строго поддерживается MVC, XAML исользует декларативный язык, схожий с XML для описания интерфейсов, что более интуитивно и удобно. В общем, масса плюсов, особенно для тех, кто хочет

> сделать его еще более цветастее, еще более не квадратным

Answer (score 1):

Я когда делал дипломную роботу тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой, мне помогло вот [это](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfxMoyy2D1k)!

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендую Вам сделать для новых окон WPF-контролы и положить их на Windows-формы через хосты.

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно именно окно WPF. Контролами дело полностью не решить...